# NetworkX extensibility for custom storage of nodes/edges

Tags: python, networkx

Does NetworkX support customization of where nodes, edges and attributes are stored? For example, I would like to try 2 options:

1. Using something like LevelDB / Kyoto Cabinet as a backing store.
2. Using some distributed database (Neo4j or even HBase - I only need distributed storage of the nodes/edges) as a backing store.

What are the extensibility points of NetworkX to support such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post the nuances of setting up NetworkX for external storage. Kikohs is correct in pointing out that there are factories for each of the dictionaries. These can be overridden.

For persisted storage the only dictionary that really needs special attention is the node dictionary.

Special attention must be given to how the dict-like implementation behaves. There is code in the NetworkX classes that change values returned from the dictionary in-memory without setting them back.

For example things like:

```
self.succ[u][v]=datadict
self.pred[v][u]=datadict
```

These values will not be persisted back to the storage backend. To accommodate for this, I have used a memory cache that holds objects in memory and when they are evicted it writes them to the underlying storage.

For the in-memory cache I used `cachetools`. For the eviction see: [Python functools.lru_cache eviction callback or equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29470958/python-functools-lru-cache-eviction-callback-or-equivalent)

For the underlying storage I used `plyvel` (https://plyvel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which is a Python interface for LevelDB.

I also give the implementation of the dictionary bellow. Note there are still errors and bugs in the code, and it has not been tested properly, but you get the general idea.

```
class PlyvelBatchWrite(object):
    def __init__(self, plv_dict):
        self.__batch = plv_dict._db.write_batch()
        self.__plvd = plv_dict

    def set(self, key, val):
        self.__batch.put(self.__plvd.serializer.pack(key), self.__plvd.serializer.pack(val))

    def delete(self, key):
        self.__batch.delete(self.__plvd.serializer.pack(key))

    def clear(self):
        self.__batch.clear()

    def commit(self):
        self.__batch.write()


class PlyvelDict(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, directory='', db=None, serializer_factory=None, cache_factory=None, **kwargs):
        self.__directory = directory
        ensure_directory(directory)
        if isinstance(db, str) or db is None:
            if db is None:
                # generate UUID
                db = str(uuid.uuid4())
            self.__db = db
            db = plyvel.DB(self.name(), **kwargs)
        else:
            self.__db = kwargs['db']
        self._db = db
        if serializer_factory:
            self.serializer = serializer_factory()
        else:
            self.serializer = None
        if cache_factory:
            self.__cache = cache_factory(self.__cache_miss, self.__cache_evict)
        else:
            self.__cache = None

    def name(self):
        full_path = os.path.join(self.__directory, self.__db)
        return full_path

    def __cache_miss(self, key):
        b_item = self._db.get(self.serializer.pack(key))
        if b_item is not None:
            return self.serializer.unpack(b_item)
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)

    def __cache_evict(self, key, val):
        self._db.put(self.serializer.pack(key), self.serializer.pack(val))

    def __copy__(self):
        return type(self)(self.__directory, self._db, type(self.serializer), type(self.__cache), db=self.__db)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__cache[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.__cache:
            self.__cache[key] = value
        self.__write_to_db(key, value)

    def __write_to_db(self, key, value):
        self._db.put(self.serializer.pack(key), self.serializer.pack(value))

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if key in self.__cache:
            del self.__cache[key]
        self._db.delete(self.serializer.pack(key))

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iterkeys()

    def __keytransform__(self, key):
        return key

    def __len__(self):
        return self.count()

    def __del__(self):
        self.flush()
        if not self._db.closed:
            self._db.close()

    # improved methods
    def flush(self, write_to_db=False):
        if self.__cache:
            if write_to_db:
                batch = self.set_batch()
                for key, val in self.__cache.items():
                    batch.set(key, val)
                batch.commit()
            self.__cache.clear()

    def set_batch(self):
        return PlyvelBatchWrite(self)

    def iteritems(self):
        self.flush()
        for key, value in self._db.iterator(include_key=True, include_value=True):
            yield (self.serializer.unpack(key), self.serializer.unpack(value))

    def iterkeys(self):
        self.flush()
        for key in self._db.iterator(include_key=True, include_value=False):
            yield self.serializer.unpack(key)

    def itervalues(self):
        self.flush()
        for val in self._db.iterator(include_key=False, include_value=True):
            yield self.serializer.unpack(val)

    def keys(self):
        self.flush()
        # fixes default method which calls __len__
        return list(self.iterkeys())

    def values(self):
        self.flush()
        return list(self.itervalues())

    def has_key(self, key):
        return key in self

    def clear(self):
        self.flush()
        for k in self:
            del self[k]

    def count(self):
        self.flush()
        return sum(1 for key in self)
```

And the graph class:

```
class PersistedGraph(nx.Graph):
    def __init__(self, data=None, node_dict_factory=None, adjlist_dict_factory=None, edge_attr_dict_factory=None,
                 **attr):
        if node_dict_factory:
            self.node_dict_factory = node_dict_factory
        if adjlist_dict_factory:
            self.adjlist_dict_factory = adjlist_dict_factory
        if edge_attr_dict_factory:
            self.edge_attr_dict_factory = edge_attr_dict_factory
        nx.Graph.__init__(self, data, **attr)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to extend networkx by subclassing the **Graph** class and providing user-defined factories functions.
Those functions could query a database and cache the results in the dictionaries used by networkx.

I couldn't find those lines from the online documentation but in the [code](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/classes/graph.py) you have:

**Subclasses (Advanced):**

The Graph class uses a dict-of-dict-of-dict data structure.

The outer dict (node_dict) holds adjacency lists keyed by node.
The next dict (adjlist) represents the adjacency list and holds
edge data keyed by neighbor.  The inner dict (edge_attr) represents
the edge data and holds edge attribute values keyed by attribute names.

Each of these three dicts can be **replaced by a user defined 
dict-like object**. In general, the dict-like features should be
maintained but extra features can be added. To replace one of the
dicts create a new graph class by changing the class(!) variable
holding the factory for that dict-like structure. The variable names
are node_dict_factory, adjlist_dict_factory and edge_attr_dict_factory.

```
    node_dict_factory : function, (default: dict)
    Factory function to be used to create the outer-most dict
    in the data structure that holds adjacency lists keyed by node.
    It should require no arguments and return a dict-like object.

    adjlist_dict_factory : function, (default: dict)
    Factory function to be used to create the adjacency list
    dict which holds edge data keyed by neighbor.
    It should require no arguments and return a dict-like object

    edge_attr_dict_factory : function, (default: dict)
    Factory function to be used to create the edge attribute
    dict which holds attrbute values keyed by attribute name.
    It should require no arguments and return a dict-like object.
```

I am not aware of any official extension for networkx.